# Magento native file PHP function - public function getItemOptionsValue(): float

Tags: magento2, php

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/ConfiguredOptions.php

This is file in magento native version 2.2.4

```
/**
     * Get value of configured options.
     *
     * @param float $basePrice
     * @param ItemInterface $item
     * @return float
     */
    public function getItemOptionsValue(float $basePrice, ItemInterface $item): float
    {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $value = 0.;
        $optionIds = $item->getOptionByCode('option_ids');
        if ($optionIds) {
            foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
                $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
                if ($option) {
                    $itemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());
                    /** @var $group \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\DefaultType */
                    $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                        ->setOption($option)
                        ->setConfigurationItem($item)
                        ->setConfigurationItemOption($itemOption);
                    $value += $group->getOptionPrice($itemOption->getValue(), $basePrice);
                }
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

**My question is what does this mean in `PHP` because its displaying error in netbeans [see attached screen shot]**

```
public function getItemOptionsValue(float $basePrice, ItemInterface $item): float
{
...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Return type declaration is available in PHP 7 .
Checks that language features used in the source code correspond the selected language level. (i.e. traits can be used only in PHP 5.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using an old version of **NetBeans**. You have to use the new version. Then the `getItemOptionsValue(float $basePrice, ItemInterface $item): float` does not shows the error.

`: float` indicate return type, which means the return type of this function is **float**.

Answer (score 4):

This is Basic return type declaration in php 
Example

```
<?php 
      function sum($a, $b): float 
      { return $a + $b; } // Note that a float will be returned. 
      var_dump(sum(1, 2)); 
?>
```

The above example will output: `float(3)`

The error is shown in NetBeans it may older version of IDE.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been introduced in PHP 7. It adds support for return type declarations.

Similarly to argument type declarations, return type declarations specify the type of the value that will be returned from a function.

Consider this small example

```
<?php
function sum($a, $b): int {
    return $a + $b;
}

var_dump(sum(1, 2)); // This will output int(3)
?>
```

You can also use Strict mode to ensure the values returned are of same data type you have assigned else PHP will throw an fatal error

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

function sum($a, $b): int {
    return $a + $b;
}

var_dump(sum(1, 2)); // This will work
var_dump(sum(1, 2.5)); // This will throw an error Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of sum() must be of the type integer, float returned
?>
```

In your netbeans when you create a new project you can select the PHP version you want to use for that project select PHP 7 to remove those error. If you don't find the PHP version on your net beans you need to upgrade your IDE.